# C++ - Cannot pass the object pointed by an iterator by reference

Tags: c++, iterator, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have the following piece of code, a function that tries to pass a reference to an object in a set (foo) to another function (goo).

```
/**************** working ***************/
{
    std::set<MyStruct> foo;

    MyStruct abc = *foo.begin();
    goo(abc);
}    

int goo(MyStruct & st)
{
    //some code here
}


/**************** not working ***************/
{
    std::set<MyStruct> foo;

    goo( *(foo.begin()) );    
}    

int goo(MyStruct & st)
{
    //some code here
}
```

And the error list:

```
>file.cpp:190:45: error: no matching function for call to 'goo(const MyStruct&)'
>file.cpp:190:45: note: candidate is:
>file.h:33:9: note: int goo(MyStruct&)
>file.h:33:9: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const MyStruct' to 'MyStruct&'
```

The first version compiles fine, while the second gives the error reported. I've seen the const keyword, but I'm not declaryng it const anywhere, and the set is not const. Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Why are you using a `set`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because yes :-p 
Anyway, I didn't know that the set was implicity const, my bad. The following is obvious. Thanks all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `set` contains immutable objects with unique values, but `goo` requires a non-const reference. Either change `goo` to take a const reference, use something other than a set, or make a copy of the object. So long as the object is in the set, it cannot be modified, so it cannot be passed to a function that modifies (or can modify) the value of the object.

Answer (score 1):

The first version work because you are assigning `const MyStruct&` to a variable of type `MyStruct`, in this case the **copy constructor** take in. When calling `goo` the variable `abc` is modifiable.

The second version you are passing the dereference of `begin`, the key of the associative container is **const** (this is because would be really bad if the key could be changed when there is inserted in the container, the order could be mess up, Visual Studio has that problem some versions ago) in this case `begin` return as the error say `const MyStruct&` (non modifiable).

If goo would not change the value of the parameter, add `const`, if it modify his value, use the first case. In case you need to update the set with the modify value, erase and reinsert.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you assign *foo.begin() to a variable (which is not const).

In the second case, you send *foo.begin() (which is internally represented as a const reference) to your method straight away.